# 'target' => '_blank' doesn't work. Rendering click in another tab

Tags: yii2

I have following code presenting picture from database(Blob) in GridView::widget. On click at picture, another controller method will be rendered, but in the same tab. I want to be rendered this method in another tab.

```
'target' => '_blank'
```

will not work with this code. How can I achieve this?

```
    [
    'attribute' => 'photo',
    'label' => 'Photo',
    'format' => 'raw', // hier nicht html,da das Bild sonst nicht angezeigt wird
    'vAlign' => 'middle',
    'value' => function($model) {
        $url = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($model->photo);
        return Html::a(
                        Html::img($url, ['alt' => 'Kein Photo gefunden', 'class' => 'img-circle', 'style' => 'width:50px;height:50px']), [Url::to('ds-substanz/vergroessern'), 'id' => $model->id], ['title' => 'Photo vergrößern', 'target' => '_blank']
        );
    }
],
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if your gridview is not enclosed in Pjax. In this case you should use linkSelector in Pjax for other required links.
Otherwise, it is better to use JavaScript and jQuery or ...
The browser may ignore it. They have settings for such issues, of course your syntax is correct.
**You can do the following**:

```
Html::a('IMG.....', ['ds-substanz/vergroessern', 'id' => $model->id], ['onclick'=>"window.open(this.href,'_blank');return false;",'target' => '_blank']);
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check if you are using pjax in the gridView: `'pjax' => true`.
In this case, add `'data-pjax' => "0"` to the options of Html::a().

```
'value' => function ($model) {
    $url = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($model->photo);
    return Html::a(
        Html::img($url, ['alt' => 'Kein Photo gefunden', 'class' => 'img-circle', 'style' => 'width:50px;height:50px']),
        [Url::to('ds-substanz/vergroessern'), 'id' => $model->id],
        ['data-pjax' => "0", 'title' => 'Photo vergrößern', 'target' => '_blank']
    );
}
```